# Maven doesnt work on jenkins (but it does through eclipse and command line)

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

I have a few tests for CI, all in maven. The builds are successful when I run them in eclipse in my local (windows 10) and when I run them through command line in ec2 linux server.

Only when I build same project from Jenkins I get the following error:

`Waiting for Jenkins to finish collecting data[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.0:compile (default-compile) on project invalidlogin: Error while storing the mojo status: /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/project/invalidlogin/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]`

Im using PhantomJS as browser.

How to make it work from jenkins?

- I updated permissions using chmod but I still get same results.
- Why would this run through console but not through jenkins?

this is my `pom`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>InvalidLoginV1</groupId>
  <artifactId>invalidlogin</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>invalidcredentials</name>
  <description>invalidcredentials</description>

  <properties>
<suiteXmlFile>src/main/resources/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>

</properties> 

<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
  <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
  <version>6.8</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
    <version>2.34.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.detro.ghostdriver</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.19.1</version>
  <type>maven-plugin</type>
</dependency>


</dependencies>  

<build>


<plugins>

    <plugin>
          <groupId>com.github.klieber</groupId>
          <artifactId>phantomjs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>0.7</version>
    </plugin>



<plugin>



<groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
<version>3.0</version>
<configuration>
<compilerVersion>1.8</compilerVersion>
<source>1.6</source>
<target>1.6</target>
</configuration>
</plugin>


</plugins>

</build>

</project>
```

Comment: Looks like a permissions issue. Have you tried giving read/write permissions to those files to the jenkins user?

Comment: @Reimeus no, I figured that since I was able to run them through command line it was fine to run in jenkins.
how do I give this permissions, please?

Comment: Actually you should probably first check that the jenkins user owns all the files in `/var/lib/jenkins` and below and then do a `chmod` to set the permissions

Comment: @Reimeus Thank you so much, I'll do that. so in order to check that is this the right command? sudo chown -R me:me /Users/Shared/Jenkins   
and to change the permissions i should go with sudo chmod -R 755 /path/to/project/directory
is that what you mean?

Comment: That looks correct :)

Comment: Thank you so much! :D I'll do that

Comment: @Reimeus sorry to bother you again, but I guess I didnt do that right, I still get same error.
could you please tell me how / where to change jenkins users permissions in linux?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue was indeed with permissions. I had a few issues setting this up, however I found this guide here: http://blog.manula.org/2013/03/running-jenkins-under-different-user-in.html

basically you need to add a preexisting user on the server as the jenkins user. `sudo vim /etc/sysconfig/jenkins`

Once that is done, just change the ownership of jenkins home, webroot and logs

```
chown -R user:user/var/lib/jenkins 
chown -R user:user/var/cache/jenkins
chown -R user:user/var/log/jenkins
```

Thanks @Reimeus!

Comment: Please also mention where its located in debian systems, I think a lot of people assume that whats in the answer is enough.

Thanks a lot..!

Answer (score 2):

Running chmod command on your project may solve your problem

```sh
chmod -R 777 projectfoldername
```

Comment: It's not the best pratice to give all permissions to everyone. Are those permissions really needed?