# Cannot find .Jenkins folder when creating custom workspace

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Question 1:

I'm on a Mac OS and trying set up a custom workspace on Jenkins. I've looked up some guides telling me that I should use ${JENKINS_HOME}/SomeProjectFolder.

The location of ${JENKINS_HOME}, as I understand it, is the .Jenkins folder at /Users/userName/.Jenkins. So ${JENKINS_HOME} effectively points to /Users/userName/.Jenkins. However, on my computer I don't see this.

---

Question 2:

I'm a little unsure as to whether I have the right paths for my JAVA_HOME and MAVEN_HOME in the Global Tool Configuration so just want to confirm that what I did is correct.

For each, I got the file path by entering 'echo $JAVA_HOME’ and 'echo $M2', respectively. I'm having doubts because I was thinking that the jdk path would end with the jdk itself. The paths shown are '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_151.jdk/Contents/Home' and '/usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin'.

Thanks!

Comment: Check if `/User/Shared/Jenkins/Home` is your JENKINS_HOME dir ?

Comment: @ben5556 Yea that's what I have set as my home directory. I ran it again and I got a different error which relates to my second question: "Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/MavenTest FATAL: Couldn’t find any executable in /usr/local/apache-maven-3.6.0/bin
Build step 'Invoke top-level Maven targets' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE" What would be the proper path that provides the necessary executable?

Comment: Your JAVA_HOME path looks correct. How did you install maven ? What is the output of `mvn -v` ?

Comment: @ben5556 I get '/usr/local/Cellar/maven/3.5.2/libexec' which I've updated in my Jenkins configurations. I think it's working as I'm not getting an error regarding the Maven path. However, I am getting one relating to permissions: 'Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project my-app: Error while storing the mojo status: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/MavenTest/target/maven-status/maven-compiler-plugin/compile/default-compile/inputFiles.lst (Permission denied) -> [Help 1]'

Comment: I found a thread here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/571135c6-7567-4606-94ba-1f48765ac4a9/error-while-storing-the-mojo-status-inputfileslst-access-is-denied?forum=tee that speaks to it but am unsure as to how to change source control to exclude the 'target' folder. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It's a permissions issue see https://stackoverflow.com/a/40352022/7983309. Whatever user jenkins is running as, ensure your jenkins home has correct permissions for that user.